# Parse a value to an array

Tags: angularjs

I want to parse some values in the following format into an array.

```
[0x41800446c745] user.UserFile_Open+0x37f
```

to be parsed as

```
 ["0x41800446c745", "user","UserFile_Open","0x37f"]
```

How to get it in array? Thanks in advance

Comment: [0x41800446c745] user.UserFile_Open+0x37f is it a string data type? or what its type

Answer (score 0):

Var arr = String.replace('[','').split(/(]|.|+)/);

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by placing required separators with in the square braces and `/`. And to separate with a square bracket it should escaped by `\`.

```js
    var arr = '[0x41800446c745] user.UserFile_Open+0x37f'.replace('[','').split(/[\].+]/);
alert(arr);
```